# mysql error while importing database from another version

Tags: mysql

I am importing database from Mysql version 5.1.66 to my localhost which runs 5.6 version
I got this error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   '`'wysiwyg_profiles',X'613A343A7B733A31333A2266696C74657265645F68746D6C223B4F3A383`'
>   at line 5

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Query:

```
 INSERT INTO `cache` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`)
     VALUES
('theme_registry:runtime:ks_responsive',X'613A343....
```

Comment: Yes. I have already edit my question.

Comment: It now shows half a query.

Comment: It's while importing drupal database on localhost. Whole query continues  with a lot of numbers and in the end is [..] That's what phpmyadmin says.

Comment: Well, now we can't see line 5. It might be bad syntax after your first row of values.

Comment: Ok. If I knew where the query problem is. How could I fix it? I didn't write this query, just importing database.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you have bad syntax in the query at line 5. Since you cut off the query before line 5 we can't see what could be wrong. Please check to make sure the syntax in your query  looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `cache` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`)
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'), 
       ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'), 
       ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5');
```

If you think this syntax matches yours then please edit your post and add some extra lines of your query.